# Redirect to different page on leave page confirm

Tags: javascript

I am using beforeunload to capture the refresh or back button event for security purpose. So, if user presses back or refresh button how to redirect to another page(session expiry page).

```
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     
    return "Leaving this page will reset the wizard";
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>adsadad</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the script which I am using but its working in chrome but not working in firefox. And also once the users presses leave page button while refresh or back button how to route to another page. How to capture the leave page confirm event?

Comment: This won't work because of intentional design. If a page could stop users from leaving, then every website would do it.

Comment: You can try with overwriting `history` to swap previous page with what you want

Comment: @MichaelM. then how some banking websites prevent backbutton or refresh button .

Comment: @rahul When the user enters data into a form, the browser will automatically warn before leaving. However, this is not controllable by the website itself. Also, this may vary between browsers.